# Class has a friend function. The function is defined inside of a namesapce in a different header file. It cannot access private members?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, namespaces

This is a simplified version of a much larger program that I am working on. However the same issue is present and I cannot seem to find a solution anywhere.

I have a class named `User` that contains one private data member as a string that holds a user's username. It has one constructor that accepts a string argument and a friend function for displaying the object's `userName` data member. I am defining the friend function inside of a namespace that is in a different header file. However, it cannot access the private data memebers of the object and I cannot figure out why...

```
// User.h
#ifndef USER_H 
#define USER_H

#include <string>

class User
{
private:
    std::string userName; 

public:
    User(std::string name)
    {
        userName = name; 
    }

    friend void displayUsername(const User& temp);
};

#endif /* USER_H */
```

```
// Operations.h
#ifndef OPERATIONS_H 
#define OPERATIONS_H

#include <iostream>
class User; 

namespace Operations
{
    void displayUsername(const User& temp)
    {
        std::cout << temp.userName << std::endl; // ERROR??
    }
};

#endif /* OPERATIONS_H */
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include "User.h"
#include "Operations.h"

int main()
{
    User me("World");
    Operations::displayUsername(me);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What about providing the name qualified with the namespace? `friend void displayUsername(const User& temp)` --> `friend void Operations::displayUsername(const User& temp)`

Comment: Did you try `friend void Operations::displayUsername(const User&);` instead? Remember that the resp. `displayUsername()` is in another namespace.

Comment: I have already tried that and it is still unable to access the member :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend function is declared into the namespace enclosing the class `User`. It is essentially `::displayUsername`, and is different from `Operations::displayUsername`. If you want that one to be a friend you better declare it by a fully qualified name

```
class User;
namespace Operations{
   void displayUsername(const User& temp);
}

class User
{
private:
    std::string userName; 

public:
    User(std::string name)
    {
        userName = name; 
    }

    friend void Operations::displayUsername(const User& temp);
};
```

Comment: @user3502362 - You didn't try what I posted, because I verified that it works. And better ask about what you *tried* instead of the not too helpful "it didn't work". Visit the [help], read about creating a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the code. I took some time away from the code and came back. Your solution was in fact correct, I just for some reason did not copy the lines before the class definition in your solution. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

For a `friend` of a class to make use of that friendship - and to access members of the class - the compiler needs to see the class definition when compiling the friend function.

This means you need to do a few things.

Firstly, in User.h, the compiler needs to see a declaration of the friend function.

```
#ifndef USER_H 
#define USER_H

#include <string>

class User;

namespace Operations
{
    void displayUsername(const User& temp);    // a definition of User is not needed here, since User is passed by reference
};

class User
{
   private:
      std::string userName; 

   public:
      User(std::string name)
      {
          userName = name; 
      };

     friend void displayUsername(const User& temp);
};

#endif /* USER_H */
```

Then, in your Operations.h, the compiler needs to see a definition (NOT just a forward declaration) of class `User`

```
#ifndef OPERATIONS_H 
#define OPERATIONS_H

#include <iostream>

#include "User.h"    // a forward declaration of User is insufficient

namespace Operations
{
    void displayUsername(const User& temp)
    {
        std::cout << temp.userName << std::endl;
          // this statement accesses User's members, so the compiler
          //  needs to see a complete class definition
    }
};
#endif /* OPERATIONS_H */
```

It would probably be advisable to move the definition of `Operations::displayUserName()` into a source (.cpp) file, rather than having it in a header file.   In your project, you only have one compilation unit, so that is unnecessary - something to consider as your project gets larger and has multiple distinct source files.